# Ajax call with target div in another page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I don't know if what i'm asking is possible,but of course should match my needs

This is my ajax call

```
function submitForm1() {
   var form1 = document.myform1;
   var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize();
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'db_query.php',
      cache: false,
      data: dataString1,
      success: function(data){
         $('#query_database').html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The target div is on another page. So when I submit the form I should be redirected to www.mysite.com/response and then get the ajax request executed in #query_database.

I wanted to add window.location.href = "response.html" but this just redirect me after the call has been executed.

Any way to do that?

Comment: If the target div is on another page, what is the point of AJAX in this case?

Comment: Why don't you send the AJAX request on the page with the DIV?

Comment: What you are asking is impossible on purpose.  It prevents site developers from injecting unwanted actions onto other pages.  What you could to, in theory, is **create** a `form` using `jQuery` and `SUBMIT` it via `POST`.  That would move you to the next page, whilst storing your variables in hidden input elements.  Conversely, You could store `data` in a `$_SESSION` variable and when redirected to `response.html` you could pull session variables and display what you want that way ..

Comment: @Ephi_Gabay I have the same request already on response.html. I want to allow users to query the database from the homepage and then on the second page they may add filters to the search with ajax requests!